# Golang HTTP Get Request Not Resolving for some URL

Tags: http, go, curl

I was trying to build some sort of website status checker. I figure out that the golang HTTP get request is not resolved and hung forever for some URL like **https://www.hetzner.com**. But the same URL works if we do curl.

**Golang**

Here there is no error thrown. It just hangs on **http.Get**

```
func main() {
  resp, err := http.Get("https://www.hetzner.com")
  if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while retrieving site", err)
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()
  body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Eroor while reading response body", err)
  }
  fmt.Println("RESPONSE", string(body))}
```

**CURL**

I get the response while running following command.

```
curl https://www.hetzner.com
```

What may be the reason? And how do I resolve this issue from golang HTTP?

Comment: It may be some rate limiter based on user agent. Try to set same user agents for curl and go.

Comment: you won't get a timeout with default client of http, https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client

Comment: @whitespace After setting the timeout, it throws - context deadline exceeded - after the timeout period. But my question is why it works with curl or manually visiting the site but not with golang http.

Comment: @DipeshKC you will get response if a `User-Agent` is specified.

Comment: If you put a `-v` in the curl you will be able to check the details from the curl. I could check a difference between the https://www.hetzner.com and https://www.google.com but I couldn't understand the issue. Do you have another URL with the same problem to debug?

Comment: After setting the useragent manually, it worked. I am wondering why some of the URL works without setting user agent manually but some URL requires it.

Comment: There is a default User-Agent set by Golang HTTP -  "Go-http-client/1.1". And my guess is some sites block the request from this useragent.

Comment: I noticed if you make `curl -H 'User-Agent:' https://www.hetzner.com` (to remove the User-Agent header), it is returning a 403 - Forbidden response. I think golang should return the same thing if we don't include the 'User-Agent' header.

Comment: @DipeshKC if you try to pass this header in curl (`curl -H 'User-Agent:Go-http-client/1.1' https://www.hetzner.com`) you will receive this error: `(92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)`. Maybe it means something... I need to do somethings here and later I will check if it was solved. I am very curious about that...

Comment: I think some sites close the TCP connection if it is coming from useragent starting with [go-http-client] seeing so many request from the same useragent. If you use [go-http-clien] remove [t - from last] OR other any random useragent, it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific case can be fixed by specifying HTTP User-Agent Header:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.hetzner.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while retrieving site", err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Golang_Spider_Bot/3.0")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while retrieving site", err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Eroor while reading response body", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("RESPONSE", string(body))
}
```

**Note:** many other hosts will reject requests from your server because of some security rules on their side. Some ideas:

- Empty or bot-like User-Agent HTTP header
- Location of your IP address. For example, online shops in the USA don't need to handle requests from Russia.
- Autonomous System or CIDR of your provider. Some ASNs are completely blackholed because of the enormous malicious activities from their residents.

**Note 2:** Many modern websites have DDoS protection or CDN systems in front of them. If Cloudflare protects your target website, your HTTP request will be blocked despite the status code 200. To handle this, you need to build something able to render JavaScript-based websites and add some scripts to resolve a captcha.

Also, if you check a considerable amount of websites in a short time, you will be blocked by your DNS servers as they have some inbuild rate limits. In this case, you may want to take a look at massdns or similar solutions.